# Update Text in input box using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have an input box which is written as shown below:

```
<input id="SlidingWindow" type="number" placeholder="50" class="span3">
```

This input box is part of a form and on clicking a submit button, I call a javascript function. I am trying to do a check if the number inputted is withing range. Incase it is not in range, I want to set the value in the box to a default value as shown below:

```
slidingWindow = document.getElementById("SlidingWindow").value;
    if (slidingWindow < 30) {
        slidingWindow = 30;     
    } else if (slidingWindow > 2000) {
        slidingWindow = 2000;       
    }
    document.getElementById("SlidingWindow").innerHTML = slidingWindow;
```

However on doing this, the text in the box does not change. Instead of innerHTML I tried value as well. That did not work either. What could be the possible solution?

Comment: what you are getting in slidingWindow variable??

Comment: try document.getElementById("SlidingWindow").value = slidingWindow;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that you are using **.innerHTML** to change the value of an input which is incorrect, you have to use **.value** instead, and to fire this test wrap your code into a function and attach it to the `onchange` event of your `input`, like this:

```js
document.getElementById("SlidingWindow").onchange = function() {
  slidingWindow = document.getElementById("SlidingWindow").value;
  if (slidingWindow < 30) {
    slidingWindow = 30;     
  } else if (slidingWindow > 2000) {
    slidingWindow = 2000;       
  }
  document.getElementById("SlidingWindow").value = slidingWindow;
}
```

```html
<input id="SlidingWindow" type="number" placeholder="50" class="span3">
```

You can test [**the Working Fiddle** here](http://jsfiddle.net/chsdk/fpr7nekr/).

Answer (score 2):

Replace `innerHTML` by `value`

```js
function foo() {
    slidingWindow = document.getElementById("SlidingWindow").value;
    if (slidingWindow < 30) {
        slidingWindow = 30;     
    } else if (slidingWindow > 2000) {
        slidingWindow = 2000;       
    }
    document.getElementById("SlidingWindow").value = slidingWindow;
  }
```

```html
<input id="SlidingWindow" type="number" placeholder="50" class="span3" onchange="foo()">
```

Answer (score 1):

You have do one change only

```
 document.getElementById("SlidingWindow").innerHTML = slidingWindow;
```

replace this line by

```
document.getElementById("SlidingWindow").value= slidingWindow;
```

Other way is you can do this calling a function onchange

```
<input id="SlidingWindow" type="number" placeholder="50" class="span3" onchange="myFunction()">

function myFunction() {
    slidingWindow = document.getElementById("SlidingWindow").value;
    if (slidingWindow < 30) {
        slidingWindow = 30;     
    } else if (slidingWindow > 2000) {
        slidingWindow = 2000;       
    }
    document.getElementById("SlidingWindow").value = slidingWindow;
  }
```